# Mostrar mensagem se uma determinada palavra for digitada

Tags: c#, cmd

Como faço para que quando alguém escrever no `cmd`:

```
> tree
```

Apareça uma mensagem usando o seguinte comando:

```
Console.Write("");
```

Comment: Qual o objetivo dessa escrita?

Comment: O obejetivo é que quando escrever tree apareça uma mensagem

Comment: Só isso? Não é apenas o caso de criar uma *Console Application* chamada `tree`?

Comment: vou fazer uma brincadeira com amigos e eu precisava de fazer quando escrever tree no cmd apareça repetidamente no cmd vírus não encontrado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar [`Console.ReadLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx):

```
string entrada = Console.ReadLine();
if (entrada == "tree"){
    Console.WriteLine("Mensagem!");
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda :D tenho de esperar 5 minutos para por como resposta certa